# Node.js MySQL and createPool connectionLimit

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm moving from the PHP world and want to fully understand what "connectionLimit" and "createPool" really means.  I'm not trying to compare PHP to Node in server performance, below is just used as an example.

Let's suppose: a PHP site averages **~30 concurrent** users throughout the day, reading and writing to mySQL.  All on Digital Ocean 2GP droplet.  No issues.

If the site was rewritten in Node and didn't use pooling, would it be able to handle 30 concurrent users?  What would connectionLimit need to be set in the example?  Does createPool only matter if I'm running multiple queries per user?

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: ''
});
```

Comment: It creates pool of N connections and monitors availability of that N connections. You use pool like this: `pool.getConnection((error, connection) => { connection.query(...); })`  so it means that it sends queries over one connection. So if You want like to do use 3 connections at same time, You'll have to call `getConnection` 3 times and use that connections. Or better have some wrapper which will push an array of queries separately by pool items.

Comment: totally makes sense, thanks.  So it really has nothing to do with the amount of users the site can service really?

Comment: all depends on Your code and data caching techniques, for example if You've a product on db and it's not updated during 24 hours, there's no need to retrieve that data from db everytime, just cache it in memcache or redis and delete cached data from cache when that item in db has changed. But for big-data and high volume of inserts it's better to have a cluster of db to make sure that load is balanced between many nodes and it's fault tolerant.

Comment: yes, that all makes sense and very important regardless of any language.  Last question, node isn't different vs the way php does it, in that if I didn't use the pool and I had 30+ concurrent users writing to my database at one time?  It doesn't handle connections differently is what I'm getting at?

Comment: use `sequelize` it simplify DB usage (ORM) + it handles pool management itself by defining min, max connection param.